# Google Maps Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-maps, properties, undefined, typeerror

I'm new to Google maps and I'm trying to set up a basic directions display.
I basically do:

```
var Map = new google.maps.Map( Canvas[ 0 ], 
{
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8
} );

var DService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
var DDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
DDisplay.setMap( Map );
```

As soon as I do DDisplay.setMap( Map ); Chrome shows an error in the console.

The error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined

I have tried including the script using the `<script async defer>` with a callback, using JQuery $.getScript and currently I have it in the head section of the web page with no callback, all give the same error.

The full code follows (Please ignore the pre-processor commands):

```
<div data-googleMap {if $ID}id="{$ID}"{/if}>
  <h3 class="ui-widget-header">{TEXT}Map{/TEXT}</h3>
    <div data-googleMapCanvas></div>
</div>

<script>

$( document ).ready( function()
{
    'use strict';
//  {if $ID}
    var GoogleMap = $( '#{$ID}' );
//  {else}
    var GoogleMap = $( 'div[data-googleMap]' );
//  {/if}
    var Map = null;
    var DService = null;
    var DDisplay = null;

    GoogleMap.resizable( { animate: true, animateDuration: 'fast' } ).on( 'resizestop', function()
    {
        setTimeout( function()
        {
            var Center = Map.getCenter();
            google.maps.event.trigger( Map, 'resize' );
            Map.setCenter( Center );
        }, 500 );
    } );

    GoogleMap.draggable( { handle:'h3', cursor: "move" } );

    var Canvas = GoogleMap.find( 'div[data-googleMapCanvas]' );
    Map = new google.maps.Map( Canvas[ 0 ], 
    {
        center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
        zoom: 8
    } );

    DService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    DDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    DDisplay.setMap( Map );
});
</script>
```

PS:
It makes not difference if I use the JQuery UI functions or not.
Also I have tried changing the version of Google Maps API, it also make no difference.

Terry

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the error.

Comment: I don't know if that would be possible as the pages are generated by a template processor and are loaded onto the web page with ajax.

Comment: I suppose I'm just asking does anybody knows what the 'stack' in Google Maps is related to.

Comment: Recently I have produced this issue. I could not debug this issue, as the source file is not available. My code is similar to above one.