# Google maps - cannot read property 'stack' of undefined- Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with Google maps but when adding a new marker to my map using this code:

```
var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('../images/icon.png');
var markertemp = new google.maps.Marker({
                     position: {
                       lat: 41.786254,
                       lng: -85.428930
                     },
                     map: map,
                     icon: image
                    });
```

always shows me the error message::

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined(…)

Before the upgrade that Google made the 15th of February everything worked fine.

Anyone know why this happens?

thanks

Comment: I don't get any errors when I use your code, no matter which API-version I load

Comment: Same here.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: related question: [Google Maps Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'stack' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33162062/google-maps-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-stack-of-undefined) (no answer).

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by removing global function Error() from my javascript code.

I have addded an example of a problem https://jsfiddle.net/8Lq4ww48/

```
function Error(error) {
  alert(error);
}
```

function Error gets called when you try to add google.maps.Marker with custom icon, to fix this you need to rename or isolate your global Error function.